# Spark - Failed to find data source: avro

Tags: scala

When I run spark submit I have the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   Failed to find data source: avro. Avro is built-in but external data
>   source module since Spark 2.4. Please deploy the application as per
>   the deployment section of "Apache Avro Data Source Guide".

but everything works fine in IDE.

jar is built using **sbt assembly**.

**build.sbt** looks like this:

```
val sparkVersion = "2.4.3"
val jacksonVersion = "2.8.7"

dependencyOverrides ++= Seq(
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % jacksonVersion,
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % jacksonVersion,
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % jacksonVersion
)


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided" ,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-avro" % "2.4.3",
  "io.confluent" % "kafka-avro-serializer" % "5.0.1",
  "org.apache.avro" % "avro" % "1.8.2"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

I tried it with **scalaVersion** 2.11.12 and 2.12.8

the Job looks like this:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3).toDF("id")
      .write
      .format("avro")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .save("testavro")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this dependency:

```
"org.apache.avro" % "avro" % "1.8.2"
```